# Ghosting effect with open source software

Tags: software-recommendation, effects

I am wondering if "Ghosting" effects like the one in [this video](https://i.imgur.com/hrx96ar.mp4) are available in any Open Source software, like Blender.

Premiere Pro seem to call it "ghosting" while Final Cut Pro seems to call it "Ghost Trails".

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no Open Source tool with a built-in feature for producing that ghosting effect. However, I believe there exist the necessary tools for you to create the effect yourself.

Breaking down what's happening, it looks like the effect consists of:

- Freezing and extracting the skater from the background at certain moments
- Animating those freeze frames to track with the camera movement

There are Open Source tools to do just that.

- Rotoscoping to extract the skater from still frames (Gimp or Blender)
- [Motion Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3STqy77jG50) (Blender) to animate those stills to match camera motion
- Compositing (Blender) to put it all together

Comment: Thanks. I did send you the bounty but will keep the question open in the hope some day some open source software will support this feature out of the box. -  So long i have to learn a bit more about blender.

Comment: I'd like to see more ready-to-use features like this, too. I'm hopeful that will happen as the open source software in this area matures.  Right now Blender is an incredibly powerful program--in many ways able to go toe-to-toe with industry heavyweights--but it often feels like with Blender you're given a million free LEGO bricks, and no instructions.